# How can I export public key(.pem) from API Manager's wso2carbon.jks?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, api-manager, wso2-esb

How can I export public key(`.pem`) from API Manager's `wso2carbon.jks`?  I want to put it in the `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` of my linux server. I do that the above is to solver the problem [like me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41357080/how-can-i-resolve-the-crlfilenone-the-error-when-i-do-curl-command/41357428?noredirect=1#comment69947297_41357428)

Answer (score 5):

Run this command at `<APIM_HOME>/repository/resources/security/`. This will create a cert file `wso2.crt`.

```
keytool -export -alias wso2carbon -file wso2.crt -keystore wso2carbon.jks
```

Password of default keystore is `wso2carbon`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use openssl to extract the public key of the server.

1. Start the server
2. execute the command "openssl s_client -connect :" 
   e.g openssl s_client -connect localhost:8243
3. Copy the cert(BEGIN CERTIFICATE to END CERTIFICATE) from the result

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

4. open the /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt  and append the  cert content retrieved in step 3

Comment: why is it "localhost:8243"?   Then why does The API Console generate the     
ip "https://172.17.0.1"?